# Change PHP version on server using .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to change php version (from 7.1.22 to 5.6) using php-cgi on the server.

I've setup symbolic link `/cgi-bin/php-cgi` with target on `/path/to/php-cgi56`.

.htaccess:

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php
Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php-cgi
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php5

<IfDefine SSL>
    AddHandler php-cgi .php
    Action php-cgi https://secure.name.com/domain.com/cgi-bin/php-cgi
</IfDefine>
```

But it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why would you wanna change back to unsupported php version?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Have an application that works only on previous versions.

Comment: No. upgrade your application to work with newer version